# Не работает анимация границ при изменении ширины и высоты блока

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Пожалуйста, помогите в коде с анимацией границ.
Меняю исходную ширину и высоту блока, в результате анимация  верхней и левой 
границы блока работает, а вот внизу и справа нет.
Как не менял параметры не могу добиться одновременного появление анимации всех границ блока [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sandi/j67LG/)

Comment: так у вас же box меньше по размерам чем SVG картинка, потому линии бегают где-то там за границами, и по этому же только верхний угол видно. Если размер box сделать побольше скажем 600х600 то видно что все 4 линии бегают. Разбирайтесь с размерами блоков.

Comment: дело все в том что именно такого размера мне блок и нужен, а вот размеры svg картинки подправить под блок не получается.

Answer (score 7):

Автор вопроса видимо взял пример из [первоисточника.](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/26/creating-a-border-animation-effect-with-svg-and-css/) и попытался его адаптировать к своей задаче. Изменена ширина и высота блока.

Но при изменении габаритных размеров блока нужно менять параметры других  элементов.
Так как они все взаимосвязаны, то подобрать нужную величину методом тыка очень затруднительно.
Постараюсь разложить задачу на несколько простых этапов.

**1. Горизонтальное движение линий вдоль границ блока.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке видно, что линия должна иметь пробел равный ширине блока и длине черточек. Так как вы задали ширину блока равную `230px`, то линия будет иметь длину `230 x 3 = 690px` и атрибут `stroke-dasharray(230 230)`, в итоге для верхней линии:

```
<line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="690" y2="0"  />
```

Нижняя линия будет двигаться слева направо, остальные атрибуты те же

```
<line class="bottom" x1="-460" y1="260" x2="230" y2="260"  />
```

Другими словами мы видим постоянно только одну третью часть линии, которая двигается над блоком. Ниже фрагмент кода. Наведите курсор для начала анимации.

```css
.box {
    width: 690px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2c3e50;
    background:#c3c3c3; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #2c3e50;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
    transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
} 
.box svg line {
    stroke-width: 15;
    stroke: dodgerblue;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover svg line {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.box svg line.top,
.box svg line.bottom {
    stroke-dasharray: 230 230 ; 
}



.box:hover svg line.top {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-460px);
    transform: translateX(-460px);
} 

.box:hover svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(460px);
    transform: translateX(460px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">

<line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="690" y2="0"  /> 
<line class="bottom" x1="-460" y1="260" x2="230" y2="260"  /> 


 
<line  x1="230" y1="0" x2="230" y2="260" style="stroke-width:1px; stroke:black; "  />
 <text  x="30" y="125" font-size="24px" >Block 230 x 260</text> 
 <text  x="210" y="250" font-size="24px" >x=230</text> 
 <line  x1="460" y1="0" x2="460" y2="260" style="stroke-width:1px; stroke:black;"  />
 <text  x="440" y="250" font-size="24px" > 460</text>
  <text  x="650" y="250" font-size="24px" > 690</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**2. Вертикальное движение линий вдоль границ блока.**

Высота блока - `260px` Длина вертикальных линий - `260x3=780px`

Атрибуты линий:

```
<line class="left" x1="0" y1="-520" x2="0" y2="260" stroke-dasharray="260 260"  /> 
<line class="right" x1="230" y1="0" x2="230" y2="780"  stroke-dasharray="260 260" />
```

левая линия движется вниз

```
transform: translateY(920px);
```

Правая линия движется вверх

```
transform: translateY(-920px);
```

**Пример вертикальной анимации линий:**

```css
.box {
    width: 230px;
    height: 520px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2c3e50;
    background:#c3c3c3; 
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #2c3e50;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
    transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
} 
.box svg line {
    stroke-width: 15;
    stroke: dodgerblue;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover svg line {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.box svg line.left,
.box svg line.right {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
}


.box:hover svg line.left {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(520px);
    transform: translateY(520px);
}

.box:hover svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-520px);
    transform: translateY(-520px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">

<line class="left" x1="0" y1="-520" x2="0" y2="260"  /> 
<line class="right" x1="230" y1="0" x2="230" y2="780"  /> 


 
<line  x1="0" y1="260" x2="230" y2="260" style="stroke-width:1px; stroke:black; "  />
 <text  x="30" y="125" font-size="24px" >Block 230 x 260</text> 
 <text  x="10" y="250" font-size="18px" >Y="260"</text> 
  <text  x="10" y="20" font-size="18px" >Y="0"</text>
  <text  x="10" y="515" font-size="18px" >Y="520"</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

**3. Совместная анимация вдоль всех сторон блока.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже код. Анимация начинается при наведении курсора.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Ruthie);
body {
    background: #2c3e50;
    color: #ecf0f1;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.box {
    width: 230px;
    height: 260px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #2c3e50;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 3px #2c3e50;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
    transition: background 0.4s 0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.box h3 {
    font-family: "Ruthie", sans-serif;
    font-size: 200px;
    line-height:10px;
     margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top:75px; 
  margin-top:40px;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
}

.box span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.box h3,
.box span {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.4s 0.5s;
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.box:hover h3,
.box:hover span {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.box:hover h3,
.box:hover span {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.box svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.box svg line {
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #ecf0f1;
    fill: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover svg line {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.box svg line.top,
.box svg line.bottom {
    stroke-dasharray: 230 230; 
}

.box svg line.left,
.box svg line.right {
    stroke-dasharray: 260 260;
}

.box:hover svg line.top {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-460px);
    transform: translateX(-460px);
}

.box:hover svg line.bottom {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(460px);
    transform: translateX(460px);
}

.box:hover svg line.left {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(520px);
    transform: translateY(520px);
}

.box:hover svg line.right {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-520px);
    transform: translateY(-520px);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700|Ruthie" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="box">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
<line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="690" y2="0"  /> 
<line class="bottom" x1="-460" y1="260" x2="230" y2="260"  /> 

<line class="left" x1="0" y1="-520" x2="0" y2="260"  /> 
<line class="right" x1="230" y1="0" x2="230" y2="780"  /> 
</svg>
<h3>D</h3>


</div>
```

Еще один [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710265/28748) с этой же техникой реализации.

Приложение работает во всех современных браузерах, кроме **IE**

Comment: Вам бы уроки писать по SVG. Как не наткнусь на Ваш ответ, сразу вижу как всё разжёвано, да ещё и с примерами)