# Как сделать необычную рамку при наведении на элемент?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, hover

Как лучше реализовать такую рамку при наведении на элемент?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать псевдоэлементы `:before` и `:after`. Например, так:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 195px;
  border: green solid 2px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block:before {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.block:after {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.block:hover:before,
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/jpBZGDX.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

Можно немного поиграться со стилями и получить разные эффекты.

**Вариант #1 с `transform: translate()`:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 195px;
  border: green solid 2px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block:before {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.block:after {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.block:hover:before,
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**Вариант #2 с `transform: translate()`:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 195px;
  border: green solid 2px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block:before {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  transform: translate(-10px, 10px);
}

.block:after {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
}

.block:hover:before,
.block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**Вариант #3 с `width` и `height`:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.block:before,
.block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: green solid 2px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.block:before {
  right: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.block:after {
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.block:hover:before,
.block:hover:after {
  width: 75px;
  height: 195px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

---

**Вариант #4 на SVG:**

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.border {
  width: 186px;
  height: 256px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.border polyline {
  stroke: green;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 271;
  stroke-dashoffset: 271;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}

.block:hover .border polyline {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png" alt="" />
  <svg class="border" version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="186px" height="256px" viewBox="0 0 186 256" enable-background="new 0 0 186 256" xml:space="preserve">
    <polyline fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="76,254.5 1.531,254.5 1.5,59"/>
    <polyline fill="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="110,1.5 184.969,1.5 184.75,197"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

**Вариант #5 с вынесением рамки в отдельные блоки и использованием `transform: translate()`:**

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #1a244e;
}

.block {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: -5px;
}

.border:before,
.border:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: green;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.border:before {
  width: 75px;
  height: 2px;
}

.border:after {
  width: 2px;
  height: 195px;
}

.border.border-rt:before,
.border.border-rt:after {
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.border.border-lb:before,
.border.border-lb:after {
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.border.border-rt:before {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.border.border-rt:after {
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}

.border.border-lb:before {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.border.border-lb:after {
  transform: translate(0, 100%);
}

.block:hover .border:before,
.block:hover .border:after {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png" alt="" />
  <div class="border border-rt"></div>
  <div class="border border-lb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Пример анимации с помощью одновременного смешения четырёх линий вдоль границ изображения.  Ниже поясняющая схема достижения эффекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: #2c3e50;
}

.box {
  width: 176px;
  height: 246px;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/15ofDrj.png");
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.box:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.box svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box svg line {
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke: skyblue;
  fill: none;
  -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover svg line {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.box svg line.top,
.box svg line.bottom {
  stroke-dasharray: 176 176;
}

.box svg line.left,
.box svg line.right {
  stroke-dasharray: 246 246;
}

.box:hover svg line.top {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-352px);
  transform: translateX(-352px);
}

.box:hover svg line.bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(352px);
  transform: translateX(352px);
}

.box:hover svg line.left {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(492px);
  transform: translateY(492px);
}

.box:hover svg line.right {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-492px);
  transform: translateY(-492px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
    <line class="top" x1="0" y1="0" x2="528" y2="0"/> 
    <line class="bottom" x1="-352" y1="246" x2="176" y2="246"/> 
    <line class="left" x1="0" y1="-492" x2="0" y2="246"/> 
    <line class="right" x1="176" y1="0" x2="176" y2="738"/> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Более подробно о реализации данного эффекта [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705962/28748)